# Powershell - Get-WinEvent Replace Text

Tags: powershell, replace, event-log, get-winevent

I have a large script which looks at certain event logs. Part of it is the following command:

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -InstanceId 4625 -LogName Security -After $date -ErrorAction Stop | Select TimeWritten,@{n='Reason for Failure';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[8]}}
```

I receive the following output:

```
TimeWritten         Reason for Failure
-----------         ------------------
08/05/2018 10:55:06 %%2313            
08/05/2018 09:19:24 %%2313            
08/05/2018 07:49:22 %%2304            
08/05/2018 07:49:22 %%2304
```

Is it possible to change the output in the reason for failure column to some other message. I know of the `-replace` operator but I am struggling on how to incorporate this?

Comment: What other message? Something like a user friendly message for each error code?

Comment: @EBGreen Yes sorry. The codes relate to the  _failure reason_ and I want to give the end user who runs the script a user friendly message. Therefore I would like to replace `%%2313` with `Unknown user name or bad password` and then replace `%%2304` with `An Error occured during Logon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you headed in the right direction:

```
$failures = @{'%%2313' = 'Unknown User Name or Bad Password';
              '%%2304' = 'An Error occured during Logon'
             }
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -InstanceId 4625 -LogName Security -After $date -ErrorAction Stop | Select TimeWritten,@{n='Reason for Failure';e={$failures[$_.Message]}}
```

Change $_.Message to be whichever field has the error code.